# Formula using VBA to verify new monthly data when data varies, did not work this month

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, matching

Every month I run a report which contains updated/new data.  I created a formula which compares the data of the current month with a previous month, and "verifies" the data which is the same between the two months.

```
=IF(MATCH(A5&D5,'PREVIOUS MONTH'!$A$5:$A$132&'PREVIOUS MONTH'!$D$5:$D$132,0),"Previously Verified", "")
```

The problem with entering this formula and running it as a macro is that the data does not always end on row 132.  So I created the following formula for my macro:

```
=IF(MATCH(RC[-7]&RC[-4],'PREVIOUS MONTH'!R5C1:RC1&'PREVIOUS MONTH'!R5C4:RC4,0),""Previously Verified"","""")
```

This has worked perfectly the last two months, however, this month, about 50 lines of data, which should have shown `Previously Verified`, were not coded that way.  I'm not sure why this happened.  Does anyone have insight to any changes I can make which would create a more universal formula which would always work, month to month?

Comment: Sure - A5 is a name (ex. Alex Booker) and D5 is a title of an event (Ex. 2018 Finance Spring Conference) - hope this helps!

Comment: My first guess would be the strings in your cells (such as A5 and D5) have an extra space character at the beginning or end of the string. This will easily cause a comparison to a previous month to fail and lead you to pull your hair out with confusion. IF this is the case, use the function `TRIM` for each individual cell, e.g.`TRIM(A5)&TRIM(D5)`. Anther step to take in that direction is to convert all characters to lowercase (`LOWER`), which will guarantee you're not getting a mismatch with cases.

Comment: Thank you @PeterT.  The formula containing A5 and D5 is actually working without a problem.  However, for the macro I created a more generic formula, which should work (and has worked) from month to month with the varying data.  This month I have had an issue with the other formula in the Macro containing: (RC[-7]&RC[-4]...